# Truncate before SqlBulkCopy

Tags: .net, sql, sqlbulkcopy

I want to truncate a table before doing a SqlBulkCopy.  Does SqlBulkCopy automatically truncate a table before copying the data?

Answer (score 6):

No, not to my knowledge.

I don't see any options on the SqlBulkCopy class that would allow you to instruct SqlBulkCopy to truncate before loading.

You'll have to do that yourself before launching SqlBulkCopy.